# JavaScript click event runs 3 times even after Unbind

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, onclick, unbind

I have the following codes:

```
var resultList = resultWidget.getResultObjectList();

for(var i = 0; i < resultList.length; i++){     
    var object = resultList[i];
    $(object.getWidget()).unbind("click", object, callDataServlet);
    $(object.getWidget()).click(object, callDataServlet);
}

function callDataServlet(event) {
event.preventDefault();
   var data = event.data;
  console.log(data.getData());
}
```

But my console always displays three(3) lines of my data:

```
["Washington", "Mary", "Jane", "USA", "09/02/1978"]
["Washington", "Mary", "Jane", "USA", "09/02/1978"]
["Washington", "Mary", "Jane", "USA", "09/02/1978"]
```

How can I solve this? I already tried the unbind but nothing seems to work.

Comment: You bind on every (resultList.length) widget a click event. So its display the data of it. Should every widget have the same functionality of the click event? Then you can write a single-line: $('.your-wrapper').on('click', '.your-widget1, .your-widget2', function(e) { // console.log(e.data }). Solve your resultList array with widget and add this string instead of ".your-widget1, ..."

Comment: My (resultList) has dynamic content so I cannot write it like this ($('.your-wrapper').on('click', '.your-widget1, .your-widget2', function(e) { // console.log(e.data })). I also tried this and remove the loop ($(".resultDataPnl").click(callDataServlet);) but the result is still the same. the click event run 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

Are your objects nested one in other ? if so - try this:

```
function callDataServlet(event) {
   event.stopPropagation(); 
   event.preventDefault();
   var data = event.data;
   console.log(data.getData());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're unbinding the click event on a element `object` that have not yet any click event attached to it, so `$(object.getWidget()).unbind("click", object, callDataServlet);` do nothing and in every iteration you attach click event so you will have `resultList.length` event attached.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys! I manage to trace the problem. The issue is not on how I add the handler. I'm using iScoll.js on my widget container and the settings are:

```
var _iscroll = setting.iscroll = new IScroll(setting.body, {
        click: true, 
        scrollbars: true, 
        mouseWheel: true,
        startX: 0,
    }
);
```

I change the click settings to false the it just works.